# Cutting a polygon out of another polygon with python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.0, polygon, arctoolbox

> Licence: ArcEditor
>
> Version: ArcMap 10.0

I have some issues to separate my data with python.
To illustrate the problem, I have simplified the data with figures.
I want to cut the blue polygon out of the red one. So at the end, i have only red peak of the shape 1 in my dataset.

**Example of the data:**

[image: Example of the data]

**What I've tried:**

**1.** Analysis (Toolbox) -> Extract -> Clip

 -> Doesn't work for me, because only the overlapping area will cutting out. And this is always the shape 2. It doesn't matter how i configure the tool. I can't separate the red peak.

**2.** Select the shape 2 -> Editor -> Cut

 -> works perfectly, **BUT** i can't manage that with python. I can't find any functions that access to the editor.

My aim is to seperate the red peak with a python script, and i don't know how I can solve this. Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: If your Kung-Fu is strong you can do this with ArcObjects' iTopologicalOperator and a basic license.

Comment: Erase is easily emulated with a Basic level license by using Union then Select as in one of the answers on the duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, i overlooked that question. The advice from @Michael Miles-Stimson helps me to separat the data. Now i have to try it with python. [Question asked before](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103746/how-to-create-a-feature-class-from-the-area-in-one-layer-not-covered-by-another)

Answer (score 1):

The exact tool you are looking for is called "Erase".  Unfortunately, it is only included in the Advanced/ArcInfo license level.  You might be out of luck unless you can write your own version of this tool.

[ArcGIS Erase](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000m000000)

Comment: Erase is easily emulated with a Basic level license by using Union then Select as in one of the answers on the duplicate.

Comment: @PolyGeo Sorry, I know this is marked as duplicate now, I'm just curious about the Union/Select method.  I understand the Union part, but how would you ensure the correct selection in the script since the union is going to create at least two features in the FC?  I must be overlooking something.

Comment: @PolyGeo Nevermind, I see it!  You select the negative "erase" FIDs.

Answer (score 1):

The tool "Symmetrical Difference" can also do this:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000r000000

This tool is available in QGIS, a free GIS you can download here:

http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: This requires advanced license (ArcInfo) in ArcGIS.

Comment: Symmetrical Difference can be easily emulated with a Basic level license by using Union then Select.

Comment: Thanks, Roy. Good to know, that is possible in QGIS, but i can only use ArcGIS with a basic level license.