# Removing part of polygon from another using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, erase

Now I have shp of a county, which includes lake part and land part.

I only have shp of the lake part but I need the land part.

How can i get the land part?

I think there should be some tools doing this, but I don't know its name. Clip is totally doing the reverse work.

Comment: Another duplicate with other options: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103746/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an Erase tool in the Overlay toolset that should be what you're looking for.  Input county, erase feature is the lake and the output should be the land.

Comment: That's an ArcInfo (advanced) tool. Another trick that works is to load both in ArcMap, select all the lakes, start editing, Editor:Merge the lakes into a single geometry then use Editor:Clip... to clip that portion out from the county. This can be done with any license level. It is important to dissolve the lakes first as the Editor:clip will only work with a single geometry selected. If you do not want to dissolve the lakes then be prepared to select each one manually and then clip.