# Creating feature from empty space in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, editing, basic-license-level

[image]

If you see below, I would like to create features from the empty space. What is the easiest way to complete this? The freehand tool was sloppy and difficult.

I am using ArcMap 10.2. I have a Basic License, but my company has Advanced available if needed.

The colored areas are part of one feature class, and I would like to include the empty areas as part of that feature class. It can be either one feature or many.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? I think I see 7 "empty spaces" are you asking how to create one polygon feature for each of them or something else?

Comment: ST_Difference in most spatial databases should do this.

Comment: I am using 10.2 ArcMap. Yes, those are "the empty spaces". It can be one polygon or multiple.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ArcMap and have an Advanced license you can create a polygon feature class over the one in your image and then use the erase identity tool with the original polygon as the erase features. If you don't have the advanced license and don't want to shell out the dough for one you can download QGIS and do the same operation with the difference tool.

Comment: There is an easy workaround for Erase that uses Union with a Basic level license but if this user tells us that they are looking for an ArcGIS for Desktop then I would propose a different workflow to this.

Comment: I would love to know that workaround. Can you point me towards it?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/103754/115