# SDO Geometry Cut Out Overlap

Tags: sdo-geometry

I am looking to find a way using SDO Geometry to overlay two polygons, Polygon A and Polygon B. I consider Polygon A to be my bottom layer. Wherever Polygon B overlaps Polygon A, I want to cut that geography out of Polygon A. Basically, the geography of Polygon B will take precedence over Polygon, without getting rid of all of Polygon A.

My intent is to throw the now-modified Polygon A and Polygon B into a new Feature Class. This Feature Class will eventually be made into an ArcGIS Service.

Some Visuals:

Blue = Polygon A

Red = Polygon B

[image]

When we place Polygon B on Polygon A. We'll cut out where Polygon B is. If we think of this example as 1 layer, this would also be the intended end result.

[image]

Polygon A after we remove the chunk where Polygon B was.

[image]

Edit: This was marked as a duplicate. Although I can see how this is a duplicate from an ArcGIS Perspective, the answer that was marked as duplicate did not mention anything about SDO Geometry. I would like to see if there is an option available via SDO Geometry as well,(Even if it's not the *best* solution) in the event that I must end up using SDO. I've removed the references to ArcMap to designate this as more of an SDO Question.

Comment: Do you have an Advanced (ArcInfo) license?  Have a look at the [Erase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/erase.htm) tool.

Comment: If you don't have Advanced license, look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103746/creating-feature-class-from-area-in-one-layer-not-covered-by-another-layer-using/103754#103754

Comment: Erase, union, and arcpy.Geometry functions would all work; it's reasonable to assume that Oracle has a difference operator